# How can I test terraform import in acceptance tests?

Tags: go, terraform

I found this [article](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/resources/import.html#resource-acceptance-testing-implementation) about testing `tf import` in acceptance tests:

```
func TestAccExampleThing_basic(t *testing.T) {
  /* ... potentially existing acceptance testing logic ... */

  resource.ParallelTest(t, resource.TestCase{
    /* ... existing TestCase functions ... */
    Steps: []resource.TestStep{
      /* ... existing TestStep ... */
      {
        ResourceName:      "example_thing.test",
        ImportState:       true,
        ImportStateVerify: true,
      },
    },
  })
}
```

But it's still very confusing to me though. Let's say `existing TestCase function` will initialize some small config & run `tf plan & tf apply` so tf state file won't be empty and then what exactly will happen during step (test case) #2? The way I think about it there should be an error or something if we try to import the resource that's already in tf state locally (after step#1), right?

Or what's even more confusing, this combined [test](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/ac06ced75cba0daf09fef2938752ad13cc6fff6e/aws/resource_aws_cloudwatch_composite_alarm_test.go#L151) where steps #2, and #4 are both imports in `terraform-provider-aws` (as far as I can see step#3 updated one of the attributes in our state that was created in step#1 but what exactly step#2 and step#4 does)?

Comment: This would probably be better addressed by someone from a Golang perspective, but I believe the testing framework would discard the state (i.e. possibly out of scope garbage collection) after the supporting functions terminate.

Comment: Which supporting functions do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setup for testing import is correct. Adding steps with `ImportState` and `ImportStateVerify` should be enough.

Testing import is implemented in `terraform-provider-sdk` [`testStepNewImportState`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/fa81bfcad90ed4e2b688d0070390fd311a5449df/helper/resource/testing_new_import_state.go)  function. How it works:

1. Previous step applies terraform config using testcase workdir and state.
2. If next step sets `ImportState` to true, use `ResourceName` to grab resource `id` from testcase state (or use `ImportStateIdFunc` or `ImportStateId` if they are set for this step).
3. Create empty workdir, initialize new empty state, and import resource given resource name and id from previous step. There would be no conflicts since this is a separate empty state.
4. If `ImportStateVerify` is true, compare resource states from previous step and import step, they should be identical.
5. If `ImportStateCheck` function is set, use this function for custom state validation. This can be used in case if direct state comparison will be not valid.
6. Discard temporary workdir.

Comment: Hi, I am working on a resource that does not support creating. I can only read and update it. In order to update it I need to import it. However, in terraform, we can only import a resource if the config for that resource was created in the last step. What can I do in this case? Is there a way to manually specify the config that won't be applied before import?

Comment: @AniketKariya Hi! I believe in this case it would be better to restructure your code in a way that terraform will "adopt" this resource on the first apply. Similar to [`aws_default_vpc`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/default_vpc). See code example [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/f2bd7eecca5363d2dd4dd75fc2e80afafa9df066/internal/service/ec2/vpc_default_vpc.go#L169).